# How can I parse a Json column of a Hive table using a Json serde?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I am trying to load de-serialized json events into different tables, based on the name of the event.

Right now I have all the events in the same table, the table has only two columns EventName and Payload (the payload stores the json representation of the event):

```
CREATE TABLE event( EventName STRING, Payload STRING)
```

So basically what i want is to load the data in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TempEvent ( Column1 STRING, Column2 STRING, Column3 STRING )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

And load the events with something like:

```
INSERT INTO TempEvent select Payload from event where EventName='TempEvent';
```

But hive is throwing an exception saying that the destination table has 3 columns, and the select statement just 1.

Is there other way to acomplish this or i am doing something wrong?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON serde requires a table with one JSON per line in order to use it. So it won't work with your input table because the line

```
TempEvent, {"Column1":"value1","Column2":"value2","Column3":"value3"}
```

is not a valid JSON. So first you need to move it into a new intermediate table which just contains valid JSON, and then populate the JSON serde table from there using `load data`:

```
create table event_json (Payload string)
stored as textfile;

insert into table event_json 
select Payload from event
where EventName='TempEvent';

create table TempEvent (Column1 string, Column2 string, Column3 string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';

load data inpath '/user/hive/warehouse/event_json' overwrite into table TempEvent;
```

Then you can extract the columns like this:

```
select Column1, Column2, Column3
from TempEvent;
```

Of course all of this processing would not be necessary if your source table was valid JSON originally, you could just create the TempEvent table as as an `external table` and pull data directly from it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried that but i am getting an error when trying to accessing any of the childs of the Payload object, i am getting this **. Operator is only supported on struct or list of struct types 'Column1'** , when trying to issue this query: **select Payload.Column1 from TempEvent;**

Comment: Hey wichon, I've edited my answer, I've had to add another step. Hopefully it should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks bro, just what I feared, currently i am reading the events from a Kinesis stream, and i added the EventName to each document to distinguish the events inside the stream, so i guess i will have to flush the events payload to a storage in order to load them later into their respective event table.

Comment: When you add the EventName, why not do it like this: `{EventName: "TempEvent", "Payload": {"Column1":"value1","Column2":"value2","Column3":"value3"}}` Then you will have valid JSON and you can read directly with the serde.

Comment: Thats a good idea, my only concern is that the events will not have the same structure, but let me try it, thanks men :D