# Ingesting from Existing Table string field in Serde

Tags: hive, hive-serde

I'm looking to parse out a json string in HIVE using Serde, but don't see an easy way of doing so from a string already in HIVE tables. Do you know how I can do this?

To make my scenario more understandable, here is a butchered example I may try:

```
ADD JAR hdfs:////user/d/libs/json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar;

CREATE Temporary TABLE TN (v string);
Insert overwrite table TN select '
[
    {"t1":31646203,"t2":"h","s1":
       [
         {"r1":"w","r2":"w2"}
       ]
     }
]' as v;

CREATE TABLE deserializeThis (jsonDeserialized array<struct<t1:int,t2:string,s1:array<struct<r1:string, r2:string>>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';

Insert overwrite table deserializeThis select v FROM TN;
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hive DeSerializer works on file system not on table..

Comment: I see - so this should probably work then:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603403/how-can-i-parse-a-json-column-of-a-hive-table-using-a-json-serde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use SerDe we can operate on the file system level. To do this, we can push the information into a table and read from that location using SerDe.

This answer describes the above:
[How can I parse a Json column of a Hive table using a Json serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603403/how-can-i-parse-a-json-column-of-a-hive-table-using-a-json-serde)